# Mirror modifier is not working properly and showing me this weird line on Blender

Tags: modifiers, mirror

[image]

I have this mirroring problem and clipping turned on. What can I do to get rid of this line?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello, maybe an inner face? Please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I think you can tell it to merge by distance as well.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @moonboots :)
So I hid the faces at the front and then deleted the faces inside that I chose on the picture. The problem is solved !!
[image]